# Connecting terminals to transformer on Power Inverter circuit LTSPICE

Tags: transformer, schematics, ltspice, inverter

I am simulating a Power Inverter circuit using LTSpice, but I am confused as to where the corresponding terminals from the resistor and mosfets go.

I am trying to simulate this circuit:

[image: LTSpice schematic]

Based on the one below:
[image: Original schematic]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pay attention to the wiring, the way you have drawn it in LTspice is wrong. Then again, the source picture is terrible, too. It's always a good thought to double check where you get your schematics from.

[image: inv]

You should also know this schematic is a very, very crude one that should not be used in practise.

Comment: Why is the source picture terrible? I am new to power schematics, so please inform me. It seems, however, that several people built the schematic and it worked.

Comment: Yes, but it has no protection, no drive control, awful efficiency, bad waveform, I couldn't name them all in here. This should only be used in a laboratory, for testing, and not for power usage. As for the picture, look at the wire junctions compared to what I posted: there are none. If you look at what I posted, you can clearly see where the wires intersect, and where they don't. That's how it should look like, clear to read. If you're new to electronics, you're better off starting with the basics, not various schematics from all over the net, there is a reason why it is so.

Comment: I know the basics, just not transformers. Also I am replicating the schematic you have provided and I cannot get the same output waveform.

Comment: Then you are not replicating. :-) Not all elements have the same values, `C2` has `1u01`, to help the solver start the oscillations without `uic` or initial conditions, or `startup`. The supply has specified parasitics, `Rser` and `Cpar`, the MOS choice will matter (they should be in the default database). Also pay attention to the hot wire for the inductances, whose values were chosen "at a glance", they're just thrown in there.